# Simple explanation of docker volume in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am transitioning from docker to Kubernetes. Had been volumes on docker to expose files needed by container, just like the example below to provide grafana container some files.

I am confused on how the same can be established in Kubernetes using volumeMounts and volumes, and how is it linked to PersistentVolumeClaim.

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  grafana_app_data: {}

services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - grafana_app_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./directory-on-local-machine/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
```

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: thanks, the link is a bit overwhelming. I was hoping for simpler explanation

Comment: Well simply is volume - is some storage you create it first, then volume claims is you require i need storage then k8s will look which volumes are available to match volumeClaim and link them

Comment: If you're trying to provide configuration data, a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) might be easier to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Pod Spec that is equivalent ↔️ would be something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: grafana-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: grafana/grafana:latest
    name: grafana-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
      name: grafana-app-data
    - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning
      name: grafana-provisioning
  volumes:
  - name: grafana-app-data
    hostPath:
      path: /grafana-data
      type: Directory
  - name: grafana-provisioning
    hostPath:
      path: /directory-on-machiche
      type: Directory
```

This is using basic `hostPath`, you can also use a [local volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local)  or any other type of [supported volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) depending on what you need.